# Swift animation

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

Всем привет, у меня появился насущный вопрос как можно реализовать анимацию в свифт без использования uikit или как совместить uikit с swift ui. Делаю такую себе игру и у меня есть анимация персонажа то есть 3 картинки и мне нужно из них сделать анимацию. Помогите пожалуйста буду очень благодарен!!!

Answer (score 0):

Для создания игры и анимации персонажей вам нужно использовать SpriteKit. Если вы хотите интегрировать SpriteKit в SwiftUI, то это тоже можно сделать. Почитайте, например, здесь:

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-integrate-spritekit-using-spriteview